# Keeping two arrays of objects separate in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two arrays of objects:

```
  data: {
    a: [{"name":null}],
    b: [{"name":null}]
  },
```

And I have two methods. The first method adds an object to 'a'. And the second method, copies the entire 'a' to 'b.

```
  methods: {
    addNametoA() {
      this.a.push({"name":null})
    },
     CopyAtoB() {
      this.b = this.a
    }
  }
```

The problem is that once CopyAtoB() method is triggered, then whenever I add an object to a, it automatically copies it to b as well. This should not happen and how can I avoid it from happening?

Here is a jsbin showing this behavior.

https://jsbin.com/dojicasuqo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same array in both cases. You're passing a `reference` and **not making a copy** of the array.

You need to copy the array in `CopyAToB()`. Something like this:

```
this.b = [...this.a]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed do what **Radu Diță** was doing. However, the object inside the array is still getting referenced.

See [example](https://jsbin.com/tolodaquyo/1/edit?html,js,console,output).

You should use below instead. To achieve complete unreferenced **Object/Array**.

```
copyAToBWithJson(){
  this.b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.a));
}
```

Comment: This is a neat trick, but won’t work with circular references.